# Como declarar uma variável no .BAT ("shell")?

Tags: cmd, shell-script, shell, linha-de-comando

Estou começando a mexer com arquivo .BAT, e criei uma linha de comando. Exemplo:

```
ping <nome do computador>
```

Abaixo ele me mostraria se ele está online, ficaria assim:

```
ping computador_1
```

[image: Imagem do arquivo .BAT no Bloco de Notas e resultado no prompt de comando]

Mas eu queria colocar o nome do PC ou IP em uma variável, e usar essa variável no comando `ping`. Como posso fazer isso?

---

Pedro Gaspar

o erro que está dando é esse !
abaixo está mostrando meus comandos e o que aparece 
o arquivo que está como nome "branco" na pasta ele abaré e aparece e fecha (conforme a imagem em anexo)
e sim tenho uma pasta com nome ping.bat e está descrita conforme na imagem[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Senhores minha linha de comando ficou assim 
só que 
***@echo off
set /a nome=Informe o nome ou IP do destino: 
echo O nome escolhido foi '%nome%'.
echo %errorlevel%
ping.exe %nome%***

### e o ping.exe que chamo ele (sim ele esta na mesma pasta) ficou o seguinte

***set/p maquina=Escreva o nome da maquina
ping %maquina%***

OBS: QUERO CONSEGUIR colocar o iP ou Nome Da Maquina na linha de comando tipo na primeira linha de comando ele abrir e só precisar colocar o que eu desejar.

Nessa linha de comando (SEM PRECISAR CHAMAR outra .bat)

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Caique. Evite colocar imagens com o código, prefira sempre escrever o código diretamente na pergunta.

Comment: O que você quer é passar um parâmetro para o script, não declarar uma variável, certo? Use `%1` para o primeiro argumento de linha de comando, `%2` para o segundo e assim por diante até `%9`.

Answer (score 1):

Do jeito que você fez já está correto o uso da variável em um script batch. O comando `set` é usado para atribuir um valor a uma variável e o comando `set /p` permite que voce especifique um texto que será apresentado ao usuário e o valor da variável será um input do usuário.

Você também poderia usar o comando `set /a` para especificar uma expressão numérica, como em `set /a soma=4+3`.

E depois você usa a variável ao longo so script colocando o nome dela entre sinais de porcentagem: `%<nome da variáve>%`.

Mas você pode usar o comando `echo` para controlar o que será exibido como resultado do seu script batch. O comando `@echo off` faz com que não seja exibido cada comando executado, e quando você usa o `echo` diretamente com algum texto, esse texto é exibido no prompt de comando.

Veja o seu teste de script batch ligeiramente modificado:

[Teste.bat]

```
@echo off
set /p nome=Informe o nome ou IP do destino: 
echo O nome escolhido foi '%nome%'.
ping.exe %nome%
```

O resultado seria:

```
c:\>teste
Informe o nome ou IP do destino: pt.stackoverflow.com
O nome escolhido foi 'pt.stackoverflow.com'.

Pinging pt.stackoverflow.com [151.101.65.69] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 151.101.65.69: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=61
Reply from 151.101.65.69: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=61
Reply from 151.101.65.69: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=61
Reply from 151.101.65.69: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=61

Ping statistics for 151.101.65.69:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 5ms, Maximum = 6ms, Average = 5ms
```

**Edição**

O colega [bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74/) alertou para o fato de que talvez a dúvida fosse em relação a passar parâmetros para o arquivo .BAT, e que os parâmetros podem ser recuperados no script usando as variáveis `%1`, `%2`, etc., até `%9`. O número na variável será referente à ordem do parâmetro na linha de comando.

Por exemplo, o seguinte batch script:

```
@echo off
echo %1
echo %2
```

Poderia ser chamado assim, e esse seria o resultado:

```
C:\teste.bat parâmetro1 /parâmetro2
parâmetro1
/parâmetro2
```

**Edição 2**

Fazendo o primeiro batch com o conceito de parâmetros ficaria assim:

[Teste.bat]

```
@echo off
echo O nome ou IP do destino escolhido foi '%1'.
ping.exe %1
```

E poderia ser chamado assim, e esse seria o resultado:

```
C:\teste.bat pt.stackoverflow.com
O nome ou IP do destino escolhido foi 'pt.stackoverflow.com'.

Pinging pt.stackoverflow.com [151.101.193.69] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 151.101.193.69: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=59
[...]
```

Comment: mais se está correto por que ele não mostra o resultado (não copila)?
copiei esse seu teste. @echo off set /p nome=Informe o nome ou IP do destino: echo O nome escolhido foi '%nome%'. ping %nome%
E não tive sucesso

Comment: Estranho, aqui para mim o resultado foi exatamente esse que postei. E se você disparar o comando `ping` no prompt de comando diretamente, sem script batch, funciona?

Comment: sim funciona sem nem um problema funciona tanto pra site tanto pra ip e mesmo serve para nome de pc.

Comment: Coloca um `echo %errorlevel%` na linha seguinte à linha do `ping %nome%` no arquivo .BAT, para ver se está dando algum erro no comando `ping`, quando disparado pelo batch. Você tem algum arquivo chamado `ping.bat` nessa pasta? Tente colocar o comando `ping.exe %nome%` no arquivo .BAT.

Comment: e eu queria especificar o local quando eu abrisse o mesmo .. não em outra arquivo.

Comment: Pedro Gaspar, sua resposta está boa, mas acho que a pergunta no fundo é como passar parâmetros para o script na linha de comando.

Comment: Pode ser que seja isso, né. Vou acrescentar isso na resposta então, obrigado.